# why are images not full size?

Tags: posts, post-thumbnails, errors

when viewing images on portfolio page is not a problem, but if one portfolio in the open drawing that appears small, it requires some time so the image can be full size. 
Why did it happen,can you help me ?

> After Opening Portfolio

[image]

> After a while

[image]

Thank's

Comment: Link to live page?

Comment: http://studio45arsitek.com/